# Int32.TryParse with multiple group separators

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a method that can handle and validate integers as on ok input. The issue is our requirements which states the following numbers as an ok input regardless of chosen language:

```
1500, 1.500, 1,500, 1 500
-1500, -1.500, -1,500, -1 500
1500000, 1.500.500, 1,500,500 1 500 500
-1500000, -1.500.500, -1,500,500 -1 500 500
```

and so on.

My method now looks like this:

```
private bool TryParseInteger(string controlValue, out int controlInt)
{
      int number;
      NumberStyles styles = NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;

      bool result = Int32.TryParse(controlValue, styles,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number);
      controlInt = number;

      return result;
}
```

This does not work as I want it to. 1.500 and 1.500.500 is not validated as a correct input.

Is there another way to approach this?

Thanks for all the help. As it turns out 1.500,50 (and so on) should not pass validation which makes the suggested solutions not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: My first approach would be to call the author of the requirements an idiot to his face. On a more serious note; If the conversion fails for `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` try again with another culture that uses `.` as thousand separator, such as the Danish culture.

Comment: You want to allow the decimal separator to be the thousands separator too, at the same time. That isn't going to work. You could try parsing twice, first with `InvariantCulture`, then with a culture that has thousands separator of `.`, but then what happens if people intend to enter a fractional number?

Comment: 1.5 is a double value, you should have a string.replace method that removes . and , and then pass the value

Comment: How do you tell whether `1.567` is roughly fifteen-hundred or roughly one-and-a-half?

Comment: If you are certain you are only working with integers, you could `string.Replace` all spaces, dots and commas, effectively removing them, and then try the parse.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue here is that `1.500` is understood differently per country. For instance, in the US that is equal to 1 and a half with some pointless zeroes where in Germany (I if memory serves) it is understood to be one thousand, five hundred.

In harmony with that, you should add a line at the beginning of the method like this:

```
controlValue = new string(controlValue.Where(c => !char.IsPunctuation(c) && c != ' ' || c == '-'));
```

This will remove all commas, periods and spaces which will work given that you only want integers. If you wanted to get a decimal, then we'd be in trouble...

Comment: Big issue, [`-` returns true for `char.IsPunctuation`](http://ideone.com/poG3j5). Adding a `|| c == '-'` at the end would fix it.

Comment: @Scott It returns false given that I use `!` operator like so: `!char.IsPunctuation`. I actually ripped that out of my current project (which works fine btw) and changed the variable names to `controlValue`. :)

Comment: The thing is you need `!char.IsPunctuation('-')` to return `true`. The current implementation causes negative numbers to become positive. [See the output for your self](http://ideone.com/9S17pr). Either your current project does not support negative numbers or I just discovered a bug for you that no one has reported.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. The project has a single maintainer (me) and designer and I dictated that it shall not use negative numbers. The part I pulled that from actually splits a `string` into a `string` and `uint`. I'll replace the `uint` with a plain 'ol `int` one day, but it's a low priority. Thank you for spotting that one, and it's been edited.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace all those signs!

This code:

```
string[] arr = new[] { "1500", "1.500", "1,500", "1 500", "-1500", "-1.500", "-1,500", "-1 500",
                                "1500000", "1.500.500", "1,500,500","1 500 500",
                                "-1500000", "-1.500.500", "-1,500,500","-1 500 500"};

foreach (var s in arr)
{
    int i = int.Parse(s.Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", "").Replace(".", ""));

    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Produces:

> 1500
>
> 1500
>
> 1500
>
> 1500
>
> -1500
>
> -1500
>
> -1500
>
> -1500
>
> 1500000
>
> 1500500
>
> 1500500
>
> 1500500
>
> -1500000
>
> -1500500
>
> -1500500
>
> -1500500

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to match `1,500.500` or `1.500,500`, you can replace all `.`'s to `,`'s and try to parse it again. Something like this:

```
private bool TryParseInteger(string controlValue, out int controlInt)
{
      int number;
      NumberStyles styles = NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;

      bool result = Int32.TryParse(controlValue, styles,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number);

      if (!result)
      {
            controlValue = controlValue.Replace('.', ',');
            result = Int32.TryParse(controlValue, styles,
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number);
      }
      controlInt = number;

      return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom culture, and alter the `NumberGroupSeparator` as needed.

```
    private static bool TryParseInteger(string controlValue, out int controlInt)
    {
        String[] groupSeparators = { ",", ".", " "};
        CultureInfo customCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
        customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "SomeUnlikelyString";

        NumberStyles styles = NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;

        bool success = false;
        controlInt = 0;
        foreach (var separator in groupSeparators)
        {
            customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = separator;
            success = Int32.TryParse(controlValue, styles, customCulture, out controlInt);

            if (success)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return success;
    }
```